# Pattern match failure

Tags: haskell, hugs

or am i just blind?

Very easy easy function, throws "Pattern match failure: get_rtg db"

```
type Movie       = (Title,Regisseur,MainActors,ReleaseDate,Genre,SalesPrice)
type Title       = String
type Regisseur   = String
type Actor       = String
type MainActors  = [Actor]
type ReleaseDate = Int
data Genre       = Thriller | Fantasy | ScienceFiction | Comedy deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
type SalesPrice  = Int
type Database    = [Movie]


-- gets all entrys which have a Regisseur, who is in MainActors at the same time
get_rtg :: Database -> [(Regisseur,Title,Genre)]
get_rtg []                             = []
ger_rtg ((ti,reg,acts,rel,gen,sal):xs) = if (isInfixOf [reg] acts) then ([(reg,ti,gen)] ++ (get_rtg xs)) else (get_rtg xs)
```

Comment: I can't see how you get a pattern matching failure with that code. Can you reload your code and show us a complete ghci session where the error occurs?

Comment: Why don't you just use `filter`?

Comment: I know that I have not idea of what I'm talking about, but couldn't the code above fail if somehow that special third value that fits everywhere and looks like an inverted T be passed to the function?

Comment: Also, you have a typo: is it really `geR_rtg` at the last line?

Comment: @dsign The inverted `T` is called bottom. When you design a programming language you have to define what a program means. When you give a meaning to programs via mathematics, bottom is used to denote a failure or a non-terminating computation. That is, a function that fails for bottom is a function that fails if you pass it a failure. Many functions will do so because they have to inspect their argument to process it. As soon as you inspect a bottom the result of the function is bottom as well. Therefore, it is no problem if `get_rtg` fails for bottom.

Comment: If you compile your code with `-Wall`, the compiler can help you find such typos. It would warn you about non-exhaustive patterns for `get_rtg`, and the lack of a type signature for `ger_rtg`. A short puzzlement, a closer look, and case closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose it's just a typo: `ger_rtg` at the last line declares a new function, so `get_rtg` can't be pattern matched now in a non-[] case.

Also, I would use `filter` to do this operation:

```
get_rtg = filter (\(_,reg,acts,_,_,_) -> reg `elem` acts)
```

Comment: @JakobAbfalter Just don't allow the code to irritate you and it'll run better :)